# Decommission SharePoint Server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, migration

i am looking into futher information on how to decommission SP2013
These steps are clear
[Decommission SharePoint 2013 on-prem after migration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298533/decommission-sharepoint-2013-on-prem-after-migration)

But what about the AD Accounts, the SPN, the rights for the Profile Service User etc? I would before these steps after deleting the virtual machines because my backup is capable to restore files from the content db backup.
Are there any downsides?

BR
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

I usually delete ServiceAccounts, SPNs, Permissions, Groups, DNS-Entries, Exchange Connectors, Firewall-Exclusions, ... as soon as i delete the VMs permanently.

If you do not delete this stuff, someone will have a tough time figuring out why it is still there in some years after you won the lottery.